# How to install postgresq 13 in Linux Mint 20.1

Tags: linux, linux-mint, postgresql

Following official instructions here https://www.postgresql.org/download/linux/debian/ but each time it still installs posgresql 12

Answer (score 3):

On linux mint 20.1 Ulyssa replace `$(lsb_release -cs)` with `focal` because Ulyssa  does not have a Release file. Use the following command:

```
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt focal-pgdg main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list'
```

Then:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install postgresql-13
```

[PostgreSQL Apt Repository](https://www.postgresql.org/download/linux/ubuntu/)

**Edit**

To solve the GPG error:

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 78BD65473CB3BD13 C5E224500C1289C0 7FCC7D46ACCC4CF8 4C6E74D6C0A35108 C6ABDCF64DB9A0B2
sudo apt update
```

Comment: thanks I tried this but I got `E: Unable to locate package postgresql-13`

Comment: @lacostenycoder Does `sudo apt update` print some errors?

Comment: yes see https://pastebin.com/dTa1UnSn

Comment: @lacostenycoder Use `focal-pgdg` instead of `bionic-pgdg`. See my edit.

Comment: I tried with all 3, none of them worked.

Comment: @lacostenycoder Does `apt` still give you some errors. if yes, please upload the log.

Comment: I posted the logs ^^^

Comment: `N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'main/binary-i386/Packages' as repository 'http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt focal-pgdg InRelease' doesn't support architecture 'i386` however, install seems to be working.